# Takes a long time for my macbook pro to wake from sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Ever since I first started using my brand new MacBook Pro (macOS 10.8.2; Mountain Lion) it has taken a long time for it to wake up from sleep (several minutes).

When I open the MacBook Pro it first shows a grayed out picture of the screen with a count at the bottom (as if the battery was run out, which it is not) then the picture gets clear and the count is done, but still I have to wait 1-2 minutes before I can move the mouse.

This behavior is the same with both 8GB RAM and 4GB RAM installed.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The greyed out (and blurred) background with the progress bar indicates that your computer hibernated (as opposed to suspended) - meaning it dumps the memory state to disk, and when resuming needs to restore that memory state from disk to memory.

To check which sleep mode your computer is using run the following from a terminal:

```
pmset -g | grep hibernatemode
```

If it is 1, this would be the expected behavior. If it is 3, OS X is unable to resync the memory state from background tasks (such as time machine) and may fully restore the memory state from disk. If it is 0, the memory shouldn't have been dumped to disk during normal sleep which would indicate that it hibernated as a last resort before losing power.