# MacBook taking a long time to wake from sleep after Sierra

Tags: sleep-wake, macos

**[Retina MacBook Pro takes a long time to wake from sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61724/retina-macbook-pro-takes-a-long-time-to-wake-from-sleep), [MacBook Pro: long time to wake from sleep, what could it be?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50935/macbook-pro-long-time-to-wake-from-sleep-what-could-it-be), and [Takes a long time for my macbook pro to wake from sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81030/takes-a-long-time-for-my-macbook-pro-to-wake-from-sleep) do not answer my question.**

I have experienced multiple slow-downs of waking from sleep on my MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2016) running macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2555).

This is the usual dock I have. It's pretty much the default, but I always have Terminal, Discord Canary, TextEdit, and Google Chrome open.

[image: My dock when this happens]

In case this is relevant, I recently changed my settings to never sleep on a timer. It only sleeps when the lid of my MacBook is shut.

Anyways, now we can get into the actual problem. My screen turns on, but doesn't have any content. After about 40 seconds, my MacBook is usable.

Comment: If you make a new user account - how does that impact the 40 second delay? (Basically - if you do less at sleep / wake / log in time - does the system respond well?)

Comment: I've got the same problem.  It happens on both my macbook pro and my mac mini.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. When the computer goes to sleep, it's as if it's off. The force touch pad is unresponsive, buttons do nothing, screen off, you'd have thought the computer ran out of power and died. Then after a minute or two the screen turns on at log in and it's as if nothing ever happened, functioning perfectly normally and quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting your System Management Controller?

To do this on your MacBook, follow these steps:

1. **Shut down** your computer (a full shut down, not just logging out)
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

If that doesn't help you could also reset your NVRAM as follows:

1. **Shut down your machine** (a full shut down, not just logging out)
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

Comment: I have already reset NVRAM. I'm going to reset SMC now. (**Edit:** I reset my SMC and I'll try to reproduce the problem. I will tell you the results soon.)

Comment: How did the SMC reset go?

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just improved my sleep/wake in Mojave via the System Preferences > Energy Savings screen:

[image]

My computer which is absolutely not resource-starved was taking a long time, like 5-10 sec to wake up on keypress after sleeping for any amount of time.

I found both `Computer sleep` and `Display sleep` were set to 15 mins, so I changed display sleep to 1 min and noticed the login screen appeared significantly faster after I let the computer sleep for a couple minutes.

I am now running display sleep at 15 mins and computer sleep at 30 mins. This means when I go grab a coffee and return, I can resume usage faster. If I find this still-annoying, I will crank Computer sleep up to 60 mins. That should allow me to drive to the store and return without suffering the long wake-time.

Note: there is also the `Put hard disks to sleep when possible` setting, which I haven't tested, but if a person wants to totally disregard energy savings, **unchecking** that and setting computer sleep to **never** should give you the fastest wake speed.